# Find elements in a decay chain using IsotopeData

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

I am trying to write a program using the *Mathematica* function `IsotopeData`, but am finding the code troublesome. Due to my (relative) familiarity with Python, I am puzzled as to how *Mathematica* works, as they are very different.
$\require{mhchem}$

What I am trying to do, is to find the elements in a decay chain which end with either $\ce{^{191}_{77}Ir}$ or $\ce{^{193}_{77}Ir}$.

In Python syntax, what I'm trying to do would look a bit like this:

```py
#A would be the Atomic Mass and Z the Atomic Number
#DaughterNuclide(Z,A) would return the Daughter Nuclides of the isotope

def IsoCheck(z,a):
    try:
        x = DaughterNuclide(z,a)
        if x in Isotopes:
             return [z,a]
        else:
             return [0,0]
    except:
        return [0,0]

L=[]
Isotopes = [[76,191],[78,191]]
for a in xrange(1,295):
    for z in xrange(1,119):
        if IsoCheck(z,a) != [0,0]:
            L.append(IsoCheck(z,a))

repeat = 1
#Then, repeat until all chains are over
while repeat == 1:
     repeat = 0
     for x in L:
         if IsoCheck(x) != [0,0] #Lets just pretend it isn't a list
             L.append(x)
             repeat = 1
```

Now, my question is this: what would the equivalent code to perform this task in *Mathematica* look like?

Comment: I suggest you show some of your attempt in Mathematica (especially how you call the IsotopeData function), as of right now it's not clear what you're working with in Mathematica

Comment: The DaughterNuclide parameter of the IsotopeData function is called by the equivalent IsotopeData[{z,a},"DaughterNuclide"] where DaughterNuclide(z,a) is called in the python script above.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a nice application for the `Graph[]` features in Mma.
We can calculate quickly all possible decays for all known isotopes, and then let `VertexComponent[]` look for the chains ending in {"Iridium191", "Iridium193"}.

```
g = Graph@Union@Flatten[Thread[DirectedEdge @@ ##] & /@ 
      Select[{#, IsotopeData[#, "DaughterNuclides"]} & /@ IsotopeData[], #[[2]] != {} &]];

Union@Flatten[VertexComponent[g, #] & /@ {"Iridium191", "Iridium193"}]
```

$\begin{array}{l}
Actinium207&Actinium209&Astatine195\\
Astatine197&Astatine199&Astatine201 \\
Bismuth191&Bismuth193&Bismuth195 \\
Bismuth197&Francium199&Francium201 \\
Francium203&Francium205&Gold191 \\
Gold193&Iridium191&Iridium193 \\
Lead191&Lead193&Mercury191 \\
Mercury193&Osmium191&Osmium193 \\
Platinum191&Platinum193&Polonium191 \\
Polonium193&Polonium195&Polonium197  \\ 
Protactinium213&Radium203&Radium205 \\
Radon195&Radon197&Radon199  \\
Radon201&Rhenium191&Rhenium193 \\
Thallium191&Thallium193&Thorium209 \\
\end{array}$

**Edit**

The possible decay chains are:

```
g1 = Union[Flatten[VertexComponent[g, #] & /@ #], #] &@{"Iridium191", "Iridium193"}
g2 = Subgraph[g, g1, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name",  GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit 2**

Another application.

```
(*All possible decays of all Isotopes *)
decays = Select[{#, IsotopeData[#, "DaughterNuclides"]} & /@ IsotopeData[], #[[2]] != {} &];
(*Identify the Isotope with more ways to decay *)
mostModes = SortBy[decays, -Length@#[[2]] &][[1, 1]];
(*Get its decay characteristics*)
mMdecays = IsotopeData[mostModes, #] & /@ {"DaughterNuclides", "DecayModeSymbols", "BranchingRatios"};
(*Aux Function*)
pos[mostModes] = Above; Table[pos[i] = Below, {i, mMdecays[[1]]}];
(*Draw a scheme of its decays modes and percentages*)
g = Framed@Graph[Labeled[#, Placed[{Text@Style[#, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, 
                                   {pos[#]}]] & /@ Join[{mostModes}, mMdecays[[1]]], 
   Labeled[DirectedEdge[mostModes, #[[1]]], Placed[{ToString@StandardForm@#[[2]] <> "\n" <> 
         ToString[100 #[[3]]] <> "%"}, {"Middle"}]] & /@ (Transpose@ mMdecays),
   ImagePadding -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @R.M I think because you are not getting the whole decay chain. See update

Comment: Oh, the code and the images don't quite match up. I get this [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uD8Hm.png) under win 7 mma 8.0.1

Comment: @Ajasja `g1 = Union[Flatten[VertexComponent[g, #] & /@ #], #] &@{"Iridium191", 
   "Iridium193"};
g2 = HighlightGraph[
  Subgraph[g, g1, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20], {"Iridium193", 
   "Iridium191"}]`

Comment: What's with the recent craze of typesetting everything in latex? I'm seeing it in posts of few others too...

Comment: @R.M, probably for the tables; on the other hand, without `\text{}` things just look... off.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it does. The loading time on mobile devices is also noticeably longer...

Comment: @R.M I find this the only way to reasonably format tables here. I will try to avoid it in the future. Sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: @Verde Naah, no need to apologize... lol. When did Argentinians become Canadians? :P I was just pointing out something that might not have occurred to most people – that mathjax might slow down the page loading on mobile devices :)

Comment: @Verde BTW, I've found `TableForm` incredibly useful for tabularizing data for this site. For example, do `stuff ~Partition~ 3 // TableForm` where `stuff` is the isotope output above and then rt.click and copy as plain text

Comment: @R.M Just for your info: I wasn't apologizing, but mocking. You need to know Argentinians ...

Comment: Well, I just learnt that they suck at mocking ;)

Comment: For anyone trying to use 12.0 for this problem, replace the lists with isotope names with this sort of syntax: {IsotopeData["Iridium191"], IsotopeData["Iridium193"]}.