# Combinatorica: Girth[] and FindCycle[] disagreement

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

Warning: run the following code in a fresh Mma session, as some symbols could be shadowed (depending on your Mma version)

While trying to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9762/193), I fell into the following:

```
 (* Let's load a large Directed Graph and convert it to Combinatorica *)
g = Graph@Union@Flatten[
     Thread[DirectedEdge @@ ##] & /@ Select[{#, IsotopeData[#, "DaughterNuclides"]} & /@ 
        IsotopeData[], #[[2]] != {} &]];
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
<< Combinatorica`
cg = ToCombinatoricaGraph[g];
```

> Girth[cg]
>   gives the length of a shortest cycle in a simple graph g.

So, let's check if `cg` is Simple and calculate its Girth:

```
{SimpleQ@cg, Girth@cg}
(*
-> {True, 3}
*)
```

So there is at least one Cycle in `cg` of length 3.

But look what happens when we try to find it by the two available methods in `Combinatorica`:

```
{ExtractCycles@cg, FindCycle@cg}
(*
-> {{},{}}
*)
```

So, two questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. What is the easiest way to find all cycles in `g` without using Combinatorica?

**Edit**

BTW, the (now) standard Graph functionality also detects cycles:

```
AcyclicGraphQ[g]
(* -> False *)
```

Comment: You've seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2719), no?

Comment: @J.M. Nope, thanks. If the answers there work for a directed graph I'll delete this q

Comment: @J.M. I don't think those solutions scale well for this graph (VertexCount > 3000)

Comment: Apparently so, since I just tried them out. An efficient (in space, time, or preferably both) cycle finder would be a very nice thing.

Comment: I don't have access to Mathematica 8, but I suspect that the problem may be connnected with `ToCombinatoricaGraph` (see my old comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214116/combinatoricaplanarq-doesnt-work/6230554#6230554)). What happens if you use `FromOrderedPairs@EdgeList@g` to convert to a *Combinatorica* Graph?

Comment: @TomD I used `g1 = FromOrderedPairs[
   EdgeList@g /. Thread[Rule[VertexList[g], Range@VertexCount@g]] /. 
    DirectedEdge -> List, Type -> Directed]; Print@{Girth@g1,FindCycle@g1};` and the result is the same. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug. *Directed* radioactive decay graphs shouldn't have cycles by definition and `AcyclicGraphQ` doesn't see them either:

```
AcyclicGraphQ@g
```

> True

You don't seem to have heeded your own warning to start with a fresh kernel, as playing around with the code for a while gave me `False` too.

The output of `ExtractCycles` and `FindCycle` is therefore correct.

`Girth` doesn't seem to take directionality into account when determining cycles:

Cyclic directed graph:

```
Girth@ ToCombinatoricaGraph@
     System`Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1}]
```

> 3

Acyclic directed graph (note the reversed direction of the last edge):

```
Girth@ToCombinatoricaGraph@
     System`Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3}]
```

> 3

Comment: :) Of course I expected no cycles, that was what bothered me. I think WRI has a great opportunity to improve in the graph's features robustness

Comment: @verde The combination of the built-in `Graph` and Combinatorica is just poison.

Comment: I only hope v9 will bring all Combinatorica functionality into System.

Comment: @verde Same here. BTW I just loph the graph. It's strange, monstrous, caterpillar-like; almost like it conveys a message.

Answer (score 7):

Edited for correctness:

I use the variant for directed graphs from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9434/find-cycles-of-graphs-with-both-directed-and-undirected-edges). I take your graph as above, extract edges, rename so vertices are integers from 1 to #vertices. After finishing we revert to the original names.

```
ee = EdgeList[g];
vv = VertexList[g];
reprule = Thread[vv -> Range[Length[vv]]];
revrule = Map[Reverse, reprule];
pairs = ee /. reprule /. DirectedEdge -> List;

extendCycle[cyc_List, edges_List] := 
 Map[If[# > First[cyc] && ! MemberQ[cyc, #], Append[cyc, #], 
    Null ] &, edges[[Last[cyc]]]] /. Null :> Sequence[]

cycles[omat_, k_] := Module[
  {n = Length[Union[Flatten@omat]], m2, cyc, cyclist, mat},
  mat = Join[omat, Thread[{Range[n], 0}]];
  m2 = Map[Last, SplitBy[Sort[mat], First], {2}];
  m2 = m2 /. 0 :> Sequence[];
  cyclist = 
   Flatten[Drop[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, m2, {2}], -k + 1], 1];
  cyclist = Select[cyclist, #[[2]] > #[[1]] &];
  Do[cyclist = 
    Flatten[Map[extendCycle[#, m2] &, cyclist], 1], {k - 2}];
  Map[If[MemberQ[m2[[Last[#]]], First[#]], Append[#, First[#]], 
      Null] &, cyclist] /. Null :> Sequence[]]
```

I get no cycles in any length between 3 and 20. Have not tried further. I now believe the code will behave correctly. Let me know if not.

Comment: Those `cyc3` don't look good (from a physical viewpoint). For example, in the first one check `IsotopeData["Iron62", "DaughterNuclides"]` ... its only daughter is `{"Cobalt62"}`

Comment: @Verde Thanks. Probably programmer error. Though I suspect the underlying method is sound.

Comment: I corrected the code. It was not taking into account vertices with no outgoing edges. Should behave better now.

Comment: `cycles[pairs, 3]` gives me `{{1025, 2035, 1823, 1025}, {1027, 2036, 1825, 1027}, {1027, 2037, 
  1827, 1027}}`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Verde Sorry, I left out an important part of the preprocessing. It now needs: 
pairs = ee /. reprule /. DirectedEdge -> List;
Should be better with that.

Comment: Now works like a charm! Thanks!